# Converting Asp.net application to sharepoint with telerik controls and highcharts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, asp.net

I Have a rather **complex asp.net /SQL server + Telerik and Highcharts controls**, client wants to convert it to Sharepoint, I understand we can convert the asp.net application to sharepaoint using VS2013 but I am concerned about level of success I will get. 
Need advice on the following:

1. Is it a good strategy to do conversion for complex applications?
2. I have a lot of Jquery code, will it work seamlessly if converted?
3. I have a complex database, would my database be merged into sharepoint or it will be hosted along with sharepoint database?
4. How would we manage user logged into sharepoint and their roles and rights?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can convert your asp.net application to SharePoint with 100% success against what you have developed in asp.net.

**Regarding your questions:**

1. I don't wanna say whether it is good or bad but if client wants to convert, yes you can do it any level complex applications without worries. Any asp.net page can be developed as custom Web Part or application page according to the need.
2. Yes, Any level of JQuery code works seamlessly in SharePoint.
3. Your database need not to be merged with SharePoint DB. It can be hosted as a separate one and accessed from SharePoint.
4. Roles and Rights can be managed through SharePoint permissions. If they are defined in your database, you can manage them with custom coding.

Let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Comment: What sort of learning curve are am I looking at? What sort of challenges should I expect?